# Cache file not found in UBUNTU

Tags: ubuntu

first time trying out ubuntu and I tried copying this tutorial on ani-cli and at the last steps it errored and showed this:

````
nex@LAPTOP-6CV71UKV:~/ani-cli$ ./ani-cli
./ani-cli: 145: cannot create /home/nex/.cache/ani-hsts: Directory nonexistent
nex@LAPTOP-6CV71UKV:~/ani-cli$ ```

what should I do?
````

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! just needed to do:

```
mkdir/home/nex/.cache/
```